# How do I deploy my Flask MySQL application on Heroku with an abnormal file structure?

Tags: heroku, flask

I have a running app on my local machine. The file structure is:

```
nobanter
        betDeNoBanter.xlsx
        database(directory)
        fetchMatches.py  
        flask-env(virtual-env folder)
        helloScript.py
        index.py(main file)
        index.pyc  
        Procfile  (a file whose contents are mentioned below)
        templates(directory)  
        testingSheets.py
```

The contents of `Procfile` from the instructions mentioned in a page https://medium.com/@johnkagga/deploying-a-python-flask-app-to-heroku-41250bda27d0:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

I do understand that my main file is named `index.py`. What should be the contents of the `Procfile`?

Comment: Aside: what's the purpose of `betDeNoBanter.xlsx`, and what's in `database/`? I hope you're not planning to write back to that Excel file, an SQLite database, or any other file, on Heroku. Its ephemeral filesystem isn't appropriate for long-term (or even medium-term) storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that same tutorial:

> `web` is used by Heroku to start a web server for the application. The `app:app` specifies the module and application name. In our application we have the app module and our flask application is also called app. If your’s are different you can change them.

So you'll need to use `index:something`, where `something` is the name of your Flask app. If your `index.py` file contains

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

like in the Flask quickstart you'll use `web: gunicorn index:app`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
Also, in the .xlsx file are some entries that are just read by the flask app.  In the database/ folder, there is a database dump.